# Dropbox saver - select folder

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to use the saver https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver but I need to be able to programatically select the folder the file is uploaded to. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as per the documentation listed in Drop box

also this feature is used to save files into multi user accounts which may have different structure from one to another

I hope this answer will help you